# Custom SecurityExpressionRoot method with Spring Security 3.1.3

Tags: spring-security

I am upgrading my Spring Security from 3.1.0 to 3.1.3 and ran into a change that is breaking my setup.

I had been using a custom SecurityExpressionRoot to expose a method for use with intercept-url entries.

```
 <http entry-point-ref="forbiddenAccessEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" create-session="never"
      access-decision-manager-ref="webAccessDecisionManager">

    <intercept-url pattern="/licenses*" access="hasProjectAuthority('LICENSES')"/>
```

the SecurityExpressionRoot is injected through a custom DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.

This was working fine in 3.1.0 but after upgrading to 3.1.3 Spring cannot evaluate the "hasProjectAuthority" method:

EL1004E:(pos 0): Method call: Method hasProjectAuthority(java.lang.String) cannot be found on org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot type

Did this move somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Try move your code from custom SecurityExpressionRoot into custom WebSecurityExpressionRoot.
- Be sure that your custom WebSecurityExpressionRoot is injected into your WebExpressionVoter via **DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.createSecurityExpressionRoot**

Your xml may looks like this:

```
<security:http access-decision-manager-ref="customAccessDecisionManagerBean">
    ....
<security:http/>

<bean id="customWebSecurityExpressionHandler" class="com.domain.security.CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
<bean id="customAccessDecisionManagerBean" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
                <property name="expressionHandler" ref="customWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I switched it to a WebSecruityExpressionRoot rather than just a SecurityExpressionRoot but it didn't help. Same issue.

Comment: It is injected into your WebExpressionVoter via custom SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation>?

Comment: It's returned by the createSecurityExpressionRoot method of a DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler (which is a SecurityExpressionHandler

Comment: You need to use **DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.createSecurityExpressionRoot** instead of DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.createSecurityExpressionRoot beacuse you want to secure URL, not method invocation