# Spring Security Use Bean For Access Configuration Attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'd like to use a spring bean with spring security to determine if a page should be shown. Below is a psudocode example of what I would like to do:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/devlogin.html" access="someBean.isNotProduction()" />
</security:http>
```

I'm aware that the above doesn't work, but hopefully it functions as an example of what I'm looking for. I don't want to just tell Spring "allow access for such and such role" but rather "allow access if you're running on a test system". Am I in luck and some such solution exists, or is this not what I should expect from Spring Security? (Maybe I'll even hear from someone that having a page such as this is a big security no-no, which I'm open to criticism on.)

Comment: this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141834/custom-securityexpressionroot-method-with-spring-security-3-1-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having development (or test) specific code/pages in production is always a no-go in my book, but that is, as said, my book :).

The access attribute is parsed and may contain a [SpEL expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). The sample code you posted is almost correct, simply prefixing it with a @ should make it work

```
security:http use-expressions="true">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/devlogin.html" access="@someBean.isNotProduction()" />
</security:http>
```

This should work in in Spring Security versions 3.0 and up.

Possible [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-anno), although that is for method security.